# Using EL in attribute of composite component

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, el, composite-component

My JSF custom component code:

```
<composite:interface name="translation">
    <composite:attribute name="fieldName"/>
  <composite:attribute name="required" default="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText required="#{cc.attrs.required}" requiredMessage="Please enter #{cc.attrs.fieldName} in english"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

This works fine if I specify the required attribute as follows:

```
<comp:translation fieldName="myTranslation" required="true" />
```

But does not work if I give EL in required attribute of my composite component:

```
<comp:translation fieldName="myTranslation" required="#{param['someButtonId'] != null}" />
```

Can we give EL in attributes of composite components? If yes, then what I am missing?

Comment: Ok, I missed the point about `!=` Anyway, I have used EL in composite components and I have had no problem at all.

Comment: May I assume that `someButtonId` is an oversimplified example? In reality the button's client ID is normally prepended with the ID of the parent `<h:form>` (and any other parent `NamingContainer` component, if any).

Comment: @BalusC I have set prependId="false" for the form. Also If I try required="#{1==2}" (or even "#{false}") it also not works.

Comment: @BalusC JSF Implementation: Mojarra JSF Implementation (javax.faces/2.0) 2.0.3 -FCS

I was checking my jsf impl/ver :)

Comment: @BalusC I have told the jsf impl / ver did you look at it?

Comment: Same problem here. The component's attribute remains on its default value if EL is used. Seems related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9205938/840977) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12525420/840977). The first one has an answer, but the explanation is not quite clear to me and the approach seems overly complicated. Is there no other way?