# Composite components: EL in attributes

Tags: jsf, el, composite-component

I have a custom component which has an attribute defined like this:

```
<composite:attribute name="category"/>
```

The component in question uses a custom UIComponent class and -for logging purposes- it prints out the category when it is requested using the code:

```
getAttributes().get("category")
```

If I do this in JSF, it works:

```
<my:test category="test"/>
```

The log shows:

```
** CATEGORY: test
```

However suppose I do this:

```
<my:test category="#{myvar.value}"/>
```

It doesn't really matter which expression I use, the output is invariably:

```
** CATEGORY: null
```

Is this a mojarra-specific bug? Or is it a limitation of JSF when it comes to EL in custom attributes?

Comment: Sounds familiar... may be related to [Using EL in attribute of composite component](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11000501/840977)?