# Use an EL expression to pass a component ID to a composite component in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, el, composite-component

Problem: I am passing an EL expression to a composite component, but the EL expression is being evaluated from inside the composite component, rather than before. The intention being that the EL expression evaluates to a string with is sent to the composite component.

I have a composite component, `MenuTable`:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="model" type="nz.co.tradeintel.web.MenuTable"/>
    <cc.attribute name="updateId" /> 
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup id="menuTable">
    <table>
        <ui:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{cc.attrs.model.rows}" var="row">
            <tr>
            <ui:repeat id="repeat2" value="#{row.contents}" var="entry">
                <td>
                    <p:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.model.setSelected(entry)}" update="#{cc.attrs.updateId}" value="#{entry.toString()}"/>
                </td>
            </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
    </h:panelGroup>
</cc:implementation>
```

The intention is that I pass an absolute component ID as the attribute `updateId` like this:

```
<p:PanelGroup id="updatingPanel">
    <!-- Lots of components.-->
</p:PanelGroup>
<custom:MenuTable updateId="#{component.clientId}:updatingPanel" model="#{menuBackBean.menuTable}" />
```

The problem is, the EL expression for the `updateId` is evaluated from the scope of the `<p:commandLink />` within the composite component, and I get the following error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":j_idt37:j_idt39:updatingPanel:j_idt61:repeat1:0:repeat2:0:j_idt65:updatingPanel" referenced from "j_idt37:j_idt39:updatingPanel:j_idt61:repeat1:0:repeat2:0:j_idt65".
```

Note: JSF thinks I am trying to update a component with and ID of `updatingPanel` which is *inside* the composite component.

Why is the EL expression not evaluated from the outer scope: `<custom:MenuTable/>`?

There are a few related answers, but I don't understand them, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205938/passing-el-expression-to-composite-component).

Using Mojarra 2.1.15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EL expressions are not evaluated at the moment the component is built, but at the moment the attribute is accessed. In other words, they're *runtime* and not *buildtime*. The `#{component}` refers to the [*current* UI component](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) at the moment the EL expression is evaluated, which is in your particular case the `<p:commandLink>`. That explains the different outcome.

You need to approach this differently, without using `#{component}`. One of the ways is

```
<p:panelGroup binding="#{updatingPanel}">
    ...
</p:panelGroup>
<custom:MenuTable ... updateId=":#{updatingPanel.clientId}" />
```

If that still doesn't work, then make sure that you don't use `<h:form prependId="false">`.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)
- [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid)

Comment: I get a new error: `javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":j_idt37:j_idt39:updatingPanel" referenced from "j_idt37:j_idt39:j_idt62:repeat1:0:repeat2:0:j_idt66"`. It looks like the generated ID is correct, but is still not being recognized. I have a feeling you solved the problem, and I've uncovered something new.

Comment: Try giving the naming container parents a fixed ID.

Comment: Same error, with pretty names: `javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":sellingAdvice:listingSearher:updatingPanel" referenced from "sellingAdvice:listingSearher:menuTable:repeat1:0:repeat2:0:j_idt64"`. I have all the relevant components within a `<ui:fragment/>` with is rendered on demand. Could this interfere with resolving IDs?

Comment: No, the `rendered` condition is not considered when searching for component. However, build time tags like `<c:if>` and `<c:choose>` will do. Do you have any of them?

Comment: No, I have learned the hard way to stay away from `<c:if>` and `<c:choose>`. When I look at the generated HTML, the ID it apparently cant find is correct, so I'm am lost as to why it is having issue. And the ID is absolute, so I should start searching from the Root.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Mojarra has for long problems with nested `<ui:repeat>`. Mojarra 2.1.14 contained several "major" fixes to that. It's currently at 2.1.17.

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.15. Yea, I moved from 2.1.13 & 14 due to `<ui:repeat>` issues. I'll try switch to 2.1.17 now.

Comment: 2.1.15 has some issues related to component state management, so a newer version may indeed be worth a shot.

Comment: Alas, the same error. I may resort to a fully fledged custom component, or live with setting the `updateId` to `@form`, which works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22581/discussion-between-mowgli-and-balusc)

Comment: Please cutdown the code (also try removing one nested `<ui:repeat>`, etc) and provide an SSCCE which reproduces exactly the problem by copy'n'paste'n'running in a completely blank Mojarra 2.1.17 project with everything set to default (unless otherwise mentioned).

Comment: I made a *very* simple example. Interesting result: it works if the form does *not* have `prependId=false`. Once `prepenId` is set to `false` it comes up with the same type of error. Does this make sense?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. I've however never really used `prependId="false"` in my views, so I don't really recognize this problem. It might be worth reporting an issue to Mojarra guys (I would however also try it in MyFaces). In the meanwhile, I'd just remove that attribute.

Comment: I've just had a deja-vu, look at this related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid This is thus a known problem and a "won't fix".

Comment: Ah, an answer. That looks like the culprit. I'll add `prepenid` to the list of things never to use again. If you make a brief answer, or edit this one, I'll accept it as the question answer with a bounty for your great help.

Comment: I'll have to wait a while before being able to award a bounty.